# ElementNotInteractableException even after waiting for element to become enabled

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Since there is no wait for element method in .net, I have created the method myself:

```
public void WaitForLoad(Func<bool> cond)
{
    var timeout = 3;
    // Time waiting for successful submission before we assume error
    try
    {
        new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).Until(condition => cond());
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new TimeoutException($"Response took longer than {timeout}s.");
    }
}
```

When waiting for the page to load, I use the following block of code:

```
// Wait until form overlay loads and becomes clickable
WaitForLoad(() =>
{
    var createGroupForm = $"{SelectorConstants.SidePanelOverlay} form";
    return Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(createGroupForm)).Any() && 
           Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(createGroupForm)).Enabled;
});
```

I then use this method to wait until an input element is enabled and then clear the input and write to it.

```
var titleInput = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(titleFieldSelector));
WaitForLoad(() => titleInput.Enabled);
titleInput.Clear();
titleInput.SendKeys("dsdsas");
```

Although this works some of the time. The .Clear() method sometimes throws the exception:

`OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable`

Why does this happen when I explicitly wait for the element to become enabled?

Comment: Quick one to try - increase the timeout. Make it 10 seconds or so. A slower successful script is better than a faster flaky test.

Comment: But a timeout exception would (*should*) have been thrown if the 3-second timeout expired?

Comment: Good point!  Have you got an implicit timeout set as well to wait for the page to load fully before continuing?

Comment: @RichEdwards what do you mean by implicit timeout? I have added an edit above which shows how I wait for the overlay to become enabled in the page

Comment: There are different sync strategies in selenium - event based explicit and page based implicit -  When you create the driver, add:  `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);`  That waits that time for the page to complete - but doesn't to cover async in-page scripts

Comment: Another handy sync method is to make sure scripts have finished running: `wait.Until(driver => ((IJavaScriptExecutor) _driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));`

Comment: Finally - if you're site is using something like angular then protractor comes with another sync method :-)   - if any of these work let me know and i'll form it into an acutal answer (there just guess at the mo)

Comment: What i'm ambling towards but not really saying is there might be other components on the page that are preventing your access the element you ened. Your object could be enabled but another script or dom item could block the object. the fact you say its intermittent suggests it is a sync problem - there are more things to try and i can try help if you need :-)

Comment: I use the wait method that I have shown above in a lot of places where I would otherwise get similar selenium exceptions. I did not know about the implicit wait thing. I'm trying to work out if I can use the implicit wait without having to wait for each element explicitly?

Comment: That depends on the site you're testing mate - if you've got a link and tell me the pain point i can have a look. Code is deterministic and your wait is beautiful... but there is something random and unctontrolled with the site you're interacting with and that's where you get sync issues...  If you've not got js loading/updating elements asynchronously then implicit might be for you. Drop that implicit wait line where you create your driver, run it and see what happens..... Takes no effort to run stuff, right?  give it a go a few times and let us know if it's the same problem

Comment: This might also be useful for understanding element.enabled  
 (it might not be what you're expecting) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186999/selenium-webdriver-c-sharp-element-enabled-evaluating-to-true-when-element-is-st